Tensorflow Keras: Running an input through a non-sequential base model without the last activation layer
I have a Transformer-Decoder layer that includes non-sequential flow of inputs with Attention layers looping for 12 times. As below:
def get_model():
    input_shape = (n_chans, embed_dim)
    input = layers.Input(shape=input_shape, dtype=tf.float32)
    positional_encoding = PositionalEmbedding(sequence_length, embed_dim)
    decoder_inputs = positional_encoding(input)
    mha = layers.MultiHeadAttention(num_heads=num_heads, key_dim=embed_dim)
    layernorm_1 = layers.LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-05, axis=-1)
    layernorm_2 = layers.LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-05, axis=-1)
    layernorm_3 = layers.LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-05, axis=-1)
    #dropout_1 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1)
    dropout_2 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1)
    dropout_3 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1)
    dense_1 = layers.Dense((4*embed_dim), activation="gelu")
    dense_2 = layers.Dense(embed_dim)
    
    Z = decoder_inputs
    for N in range(12):
        Z = mha(query=Z, value=Z, key=Z, use_causal_mask=True)
        Z = dropout_2(Z)
        Z = layernorm_2(Z + skip_1)
        skip_2 = Z
        Z = dense_1(Z)
        Z = dense_2(Z)
        Z = dropout_3(Z)
    Z = layernorm_3(Z + skip_2)

    output1 = layers.TimeDistributed(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid"))(Z)
    model = tf.keras.Model(input, output1)       
    return model

I want to run my input from this same model, but only obtain output without the last layer. So far I have below code for this:
input_shape = (n_chans, sequence_length, 1)
inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape = input_shape)
headless_model = tf.keras.models.Sequential(base_model.layers[:-1])
output = headless_model(input, training=False)
headless_model = keras.Model(input, output)

But I have some confusion since this model is not Sequential, and has repeating inputs such as MHA getting input tensor Z as 3 arguments, as well as the inner for loop, whether this is giving me a wrong interpretation of this model? What is the correct approach to do this at Keras Tensorflow?
Note 1: Model is already trained, and being loaded with saved weights.
Note 2: I am trying to obtain headless model without the activations to calculate Fréchet inception distance for research purposes.
